# How can one use Typescript to make an interface for a fixed, simple object?

Tags: typescript

I have a form with 12 fields and the resulting object will always have 12 string keys following the format {r | b}-s{1 | 2 | 3}-{team | scout} with string values. I've tried creating an interface as follows:

```
export interface IAdminFormState {
  "r-s1-team": string;
  "r-s1-scout": string;
  ...
  "b-s3-team": string;
  "b-s3-scout": string;
}
```

However, when I try do to the following to update a single field in the store (React-Redux)

```
const newState: IAdminFormState = state.formState;
newState[action.field] = action.value;
```

The second line gives me the error: **Element implicitly has an *'any'* type because expression of type *'string'* can't be used to index type *'IAdminFormState'***, followed by  **No index signature with a parameter of type *'string'* was found on type *'IAdminFormState'*.**

What would be a better approach to fix this issue?

Comment: TypeScript objects do not implicitly allow you to index into them the same way that plain JS objects do. Refer to [this](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html#declaring-an-index-signature) for an example of how you can achieve what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the properties in `IAdminFormState` have type `string`, then you should be able to make the compiler happy as long as `action` has type `{field: keyof IAdminFormState, value: string}`:

```
declare const state: { formState: IAdminFormState };
declare const action: { field: keyof IAdminFormState, value: string };

const newState: IAdminFormState = state.formState;
newState[action.field] = action.value; // no error
```

The compiler knows that `action.field` is one of the keys, and since all properties are `string` it's safe to index into `newState` with it, and assign a `string` value to it.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQEsB2CxwGYEMDGYSAkgIIAmAtugGLyUDKCumSA3qEl0gERwC0AZwCM-TLko8AXEkEI46AOYBuTtz5DRg-DACuCabPlLVIbkgD0FgHS21XHgCMhAZjFgJhuQrQr7vZ0E3bT0DGW8TUABfUFByMHwAG1w4Ih00OSMWMBk2JGx6JmyZMipaQuZWKNN4pJS0mAzkAgQURtz8lDBE8hkAazAATxhsEgpqNDo4RkqwABokADdcRN0cox9FJGrYkHTMtDAAdyLMEvHy6dOiAF4szGsCq9nTQ5PZgG0WtrRHrp6ALpIO7fRrWZarMCmIA)